# How to superimpose multiple plots

Tags: matlab, plot, overlap

I am required to open data files in .txt format and generate plots out of them. I want to superimpose all the plots together so that I can do comparison between them. I am doing the following. I have 5 data files named 0.txt,1.txt,2.txt....5.txt

```
for s=0:5

str = strcat(int2str(s),'m.txt');
fid = fopen(str);

A =  textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*s %*s %*s') ;
%%%%read the file
a = A{1};
e = A{2};
c = A{3};
x = A{4};
y = A{5};
```

---

```
figure;
plot (x(1:end-1),g);
hold on

end
```

But I am not able to superimpose the plots!!

Comment: Maybe try removing the `figure` from inside the for loop?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the following:

```
figure; hold on;

for s=0:5
   % contents of your for loop goes here
   % reading in the text file
   % plot(...)
end  

hold off;
```

Comment: 'hold all' rather than 'hold on' is often useful (when  you want different colored lines, but don't necessarily want to define all those colors yourself)